# Plugin for custom sort order for categories?

Tags: theme-development, categories, sort

I'd like to employ a sort order option in my theme to allow categories to be sorted similar to pages. Can anyone recommend a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed this requirement a while back. There's a [selection of plugins available](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress+category+order), but nothing took my fancy. They were (in my opinion) either too bloated, poorly written, or the UI was either lacking or overly complex.

Then I stumbled upon [Term Menu Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-menu-order/). Essentially it adds a `menu_order` field to the terms database, and you use it the same way as the menu order for pages. Very simple, does the job!

NB: I actually took the concept and rewrote in what I considered an improvement.

- It's oh-so-slightly less heavy on memory
- Adds a simple `orderby=term_order` argument available for term function
- Can control which taxonomies support ordering, either through the `register_taxonomy()` call or with WordPress hooks
- Fixes one particular flaw - same terms in different taxonomies will share the same order, my plugin fixed this

<strike>If this takes your fancy I can share :)</strike>

<strike>My spin on the [Term Order Plugin](http://www.mediafire.com/?6os09lh29o9p0yy) (MediaFire)</strike>

The MediaFire upload has had it's day, apologies. Will get a replacement set-up, perhaps on GitHub, soon...

Comment: Do you share the code of the rewritten plugin?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: Its working great for items where i can add the &orderby=term_order filter to. However, I can't get the default WP categories widget to obey the order. Should I have to do anything special to make it work there too?

Comment: Hi @Scott B @TheDeadMedic @jameslafferty This is what I'm looking for exactly! Would it be possible to repost the code please? The MediaFire link is broken... Many thanks!

Comment: @Flo You still need it? Errm, rather embarrassing, but I lost it! If @Scott B still has it, could you help us out? Otherwise I plan on writing a super-awesome fork with drag & drop! Watch this space...

Comment: You lost it? What a shame. :( @Scott B: do you still have the code? Please, share. Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in this as well - Any updates on availability?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I'm checking in once more to see if there's any hope of getting a copy of the update code?

Answer (score 1):

Bill Erickson and I recently updated the Term Menu Order plugin (which had fallen into disrepair). I actually came back here to see if TheDeadMedic's solution was still available to use in improving the plugin some more... sorry to see that it's not up.

Comment: Thank you for your update! I'm going to grab it and work with it today.

Answer (score 0):

I have just released a plugin that attempts to tackle this issue: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/. All you do it add the order for the individual terms, much like with pages, and the sorting is magically done for you.