# Sort Custom Taxonomy Terms in admin by custom order

Tags: custom-taxonomy

This question was discussed on [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16524/custom-order-of-terms-for-custom-taxonomy-in-admin-and-website) and I believe [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/plugin-for-custom-sort-order-for-categories) as well, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any updates to this since then?

To clarify, I currently have a custom taxonomy called 'Days of Week' so I only use seven terms (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.) but under `hiearchical=>true`, WordPress lists them in an alphabetical order instead.

1. Friday
2. Monday
3. Saturday
4. Sunday
5. Thursday
6. Tuesday
7. Wednesday

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but given that some users of the site might find it confusing, I thought I'd ask to see if anyone had any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a new answer for this, use my brand new plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/. I hope this helps with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [Term Menu Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-menu-order/) plugin seems like it would do the trick just fine here. I am also about to release a new plugin to handle this type of an issue (hopefully in the next week). I also wrote a blog post about it that will be up later next week. I'll keep you updated. In the meantime, I think the Term Menu Order should work just fine.

Actually, if you contact me through http://www.zackdev.com/, I'll send you a "beta" of the plugin. It's working well right now, I'm just spending time improving the documentation, internationalization and otherwise making the plugin awesome.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your reply! :)

I wasn't sure about the Term Menu Order plugin initially as it has a compatibility up to WP 3.0.5 and also the documentation mentions changing core files. What is surprising is that this question doesn't appear to have been asked as often as expected.  I will definitely send you a message via your website as I would be happy to beta-test your plugin. 

Thanks again!

Comment: I just sent some stuff over to you. I did not catch that the Term Menu Order plugin needed core file alteration. I think you will be pleased that mine does not need such changes!

Answer (score 0):

The [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) allow you to define custom taxonomy terms within the admin through an drag and drop interface. Going to build the code will not be easy, you should check with this plugin code to see on how can be done